# Ruby build failing, rbenv saying I need an older version for yeoman project

Tags: ruby, npm, yeoman, rbenv, compass

I followed the guide here https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-drupal-theme to install a zen subtheme. Everything went okay but when I run `compass watch` I'm given the error `rbenv: version 2.0.0-p451 is not installed` When I run `rbenv install 2.0.0-p451` I'm given this:

```
Downloading yaml-0.1.6.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/7da6971b4bd08a986dd2a61353bc422362bd0edcc67d7ebaac68c95f74182749
Installing yaml-0.1.6...
Installed yaml-0.1.6 to /home/administrator/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p451

Downloading ruby-2.0.0-p451.tar.gz...
-> http://dqw8nmjcqpjn7.cloudfront.net/e6d6900eb4084053058349cfdbf63ad1414b6a8d75d58b47ed81010a9947e73b
Installing ruby-2.0.0-p451...

BUILD FAILED (Ubuntu 14.04 using ruby-build 20150519-13-g702b410)

Inspect or clean up the working tree at /tmp/ruby-build.20150622015608.1215
Results logged to /tmp/ruby-build.20150622015608.1215.log

Last 10 log lines:
compiling ossl_x509crl.c
compiling ossl_ssl.c
compiling ossl_hmac.c
installing default openssl libraries
linking shared-object dl/callback.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150622015608.1215/ruby-2.0.0-p451/ext/dl/callback'
linking shared-object openssl.so
make[2]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150622015608.1215/ruby-2.0.0-p451/ext/openssl'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/tmp/ruby-build.20150622015608.1215/ruby-2.0.0-p451'
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

My ruby version is 2.2.0p0 revision 49005. Full log here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2baf570aa58f2fbf7a18